# Использование переменных в регулярных выражениях модуля mod_rewrite

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть выражение

```
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Оно соответственно меняет запрос вида `localhost/solutions` на `localhost/index.php?id=solutions`

Мне надо чтобы ссылка вида `localhost/solutions.php?e=20132009` менялась на `localhost/index.php?id=solutions&post=20132009`

Т.е. на сколько я понимаю, надо ещё задействовать переменную `$2` через вторую регулярку. Как это описать?
Начальное, как я понял, надо поменять на `/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+.php)/`, чтобы попадали только файлы с расширением `.php`, но как это в переменную запихнуть? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `/?(solution.php?e=)/?$` либо на такое поменять.чтобы пользователь обращаясь туда, щёл сразу на `index.php?id=solutions&post=` 
Вопрос в том как значения после e вытянуть в переменную 1?

Comment: `/(solutions.php[?][e][=][0-9]+)/` точнее вот такое,прошлое не действует

Comment: /?(events.php[?][e][=])([0-9]+)/?$
Вот эта регулярка не действует,хотя на сайте проверки регулярок она подходит,но апач её не кушает

Comment: нашёл на форуме другой подход,тоже почему то не работает((
RewriteRule ^events\.php\?e=([0-9]+) index.php?id=events [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: RewriteRule ^events\.php\?e=([0-9]+) index.php?id=events [L,NC,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} e=(.*)
RewriteRule ^events\.php?$ index.php?id=events&post=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Пишется сначала условие, в котором можно вычленить значение параметра, который передаётся в ссылке, далее запихиваем его в переменную, и в конце просто подставляем её.
Как использовать несколько переменных я к сожалению так и не понял, как найду напишу.